# Depth map from iPhone 7 Plus dual cameras

Tags: iphone, 3d, camera, ios10, depth

Is or will there be a *built in feature* to generate and access a `depth map` from the dual cameras on the iPhone 7 Plus?

We have all seen Apple's **keynote** where they demonstrate how to use the cameras to create a *shallow depth effect*, but reading the API-reference I can't read more than how to access the `raw input` from the two cameras.

`Focus pixels` is clearly something else since it is supported by earlier devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer for this on the `Apple Developer Forum` from a member of the *Apple staff*.

> I'll send out a post soon about iOS 10 APIs that are specific to the
>   iPhone 7 and 7 Plus cameras. The short answer is that **no**, depth maps
>   will not be available in this release.

Comment: However, if both the camera stream are available we can get the depth map using OpenCV or other libraries

Comment: I thought of this too, but from the demo they gave the impression of supporting this natively. Got my hopes up! =)

Comment: Yes, the depth image that they showed, triggered a lot of possibilities in my head, but their announcement about depth map was very limited. So they might be keeping it for future versions until they get it right.

Comment: Also sounds like their depth map is really only on the order of 10 levels.